# TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'BufferedReader'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pytorch, torch

```
(Pdb) import os
(Pdb) import numpy as np
(Pdb) from tempfile import mkdtemp
(Pdb) import os.path as path

(Pdb) tensor
tensor([     0,      0,  20480,  ...,      0,      0, -16400], dtype=torch.int16)
(Pdb) tensor.dtype
torch.int16

(Pdb) filename = path.join(mkdtemp(), f)
*** TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'BufferedReader' 


(Pdb) import torch

(Pdb) fp = np.memmp(filename, dtype='int16')
(Pdb) fp
memmap([16, 12, 12, ..., 44, 44, 44], dtype=int16)
(Pdb)
```

I am trying to create a memory-map to an array stored in a binary file on disk. But I am getting `*** TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'BufferedReader'`  error. Even after the error the memory map is working but I want it free from error. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Presumably `f` is an open file (e.g. `open('filename.txt', 'br')` returns a `BufferedReader`).  `os.path.join` does not accept a file object as an argument.  It expects strings (or, as the error message explains, `bytes`).

Comment: when I am giving the string filepath name it is looking that file in `/tmp/tmp_p18os9v/`  folder. It show the error [`*** FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`]

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The code that you show above does not show how you created `f`.

Comment: Earlier I was writting the file `f = open('filename.txt', 'rb')' then as you suggest to give the string so I just assign `f` to the filename `f = 'filename.txt''.